# Is there a way to wait/block until S3 replicates update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication, eventual-consistency

So there is an object in S3 at some location.

My code updates S3 object. But I need to make sure that it is properly replicated before proceeding.

Is there a way to wait/block until this change replicated to everywhere?

Comment: No need. For uploaded files read-after-write consistency is provided for all regions of AWS but us-standard. If you want to work in us-east-1, you can use the named endpoint as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/managing-data-consistency.html

Comment: @Guy, that's not quite true.  Read-after-write is *only* provided for *new* objects. Overwrites of existing objects, and deletes are eventually-consistent in all regions.

Comment: @Guy, I know about read after write, I'm gonna leverage it as well, but it does not apply to updates and listing operations.

Comment: In this case you might want to move to async model and use the notification model of S3 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html). Instead of blocking or waiting, trigger the next action from the notification.